# Cypress Infinite Scroll

Tags: cypress, automation-testing

How can I scroll down and find a text with Cypress framework in "https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/infinite_scroll"?
The text I want to find is "doloremque quasi voluptatibus fugiat ipsa eos quas culpa sed omnis nostrum enim quisquam."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use recursion to do this.[cypress-recurse](https://github.com/bahmutov/cypress-recurse) is great for this.

```js
const textToFind = 'doloremque quasi voluptatibus fugiat ipsa eos quas culpa sed omnis nostrum enim quisquam.'
recurse(
  () => {
    return cy.contains('.text-selector', 
    textToFind).should(Cypress._.noop)
  },
  ($text) => $text.length > 0 },
  {
    timeout:60_000, // you can alter these options
    delay:1_000,
    error: 'Could not find text',
  },
)
```

Comment: You need brackets `() => { return` or remove the return `() => cy.contains`